# Visual Studio Code .NET framework not working when launched through unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble getting the .net framework to run inside vscode. I can get the .net framework running fine when I open vscode normally. However, when I open a .cs file in unity and use vscode as my default editor, I get error messages because the .net framework no longer works inside vscode. I need the framework for c# specific autocomplete and syntax errors. I have gotten comments on another post that has been closed saying I need to be more specific about this issue. This is not an issue with unity not supporting the .net framework. I have tried restarting my pc, restarting vscode, restarting unity, reimporting unity packages, and redownloading the .net framework. All c# code runs fine inside and outside of unity regardless of whether vscode was launched using the unity shortcut, but running the dotnet command and any c# related autocomplete/syntax do not work. I can edit c# code from unity by running vscode without unity and navigating to the file. Thanks for your help.

dotnet command run in vscode launched by unity
[image: dotnet command run in vscode launched by unity]

dotnet command run in vscode launched via shortcut
[image: dotnet command run in vscode launched via shortcut]

c# code working inside of unity
[image: c# code working inside of unity]

Omnisharp error message/log:

> Starting OmniSharp server at 5/30/2020, 9:41:51 PM
>       Target: a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\2_Terminal_Hacker.sln
>
> OmniSharp server started.
>       Path: c:\Users\0dps1.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0.omnisharp\1.35.2\OmniSharp.exe
>       PID: 15076
>
> [info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
>           Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64) [info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
>           DotNetPath set to dotnet [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
>           Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
>               1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.30114.105 - "A:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
>               2: StandAlone 16.4 - "c:\Users\0dps1.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0.omnisharp\1.35.2.msbuild\Current\Bin"
>   [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
>           Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.6.30114.105 - "A:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin" [info]:
>   OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
>           Detecting Cake files in 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker'. [info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
>           Could not find any Cake files [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
>           Detecting projects in 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\2_Terminal_Hacker.sln'. [info]:
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Queue project update for 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj' [info]:
>   OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Detecting CSX files in 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker'. [info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
>           Could not find any CSX files [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 0 [info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Loading project: a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj [info]:
>   OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 100 [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 110 [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider,
>   Order: 140 [info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
>           Configuration finished. [info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
>           Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker' on host 13388. [fail]:
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
>           The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
>   Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
>   download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
>   https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [warn]:
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Failed to load project file 'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
>   a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj A:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
>   Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were
>   not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
>   Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
>   download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
>   https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
>
> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Attempted to update project that is not loaded: a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the log:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader The reference assemblies for
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install
>   the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or
>   retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer
>   Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [warn]:
>   OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Failed to load project file
>   'a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
>   a:\Github\Unity\2_Terminal_Hacker\Assembly-CSharp.csproj A:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
>   Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were
>   not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
>   Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
>   download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
>   https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

.Net sdk/system libraries are installed through Visual Studio, so vscode/omnisharp tried to pull them from your Visual Studio Community 16.6 installation (info for that is on the start of the log). But it looks like VSCommunity is installed without v4.7.1 targetting pack.

To fix this, go to:

> Visual Studio Installer -> Visual Studio Community -> More -> Modify ->
>   Individual Components

and check ".NETFramework v4.7.1" pack. Afrer this gets installed, reboot stuff and you should be good to go.

Comment: The .NETFramework v4.7.1 targeting pack was already installed, but the sdk was not. I will try installing that now.

Comment: It is installed, but Omnisharp still comes up with the error message. I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62124805/13118680 I think I need help retargeting it

Comment: "Retarget" application in this sense means changing "Target framework" tag inside .csprojs. Whatever you do there will be overriden by Unity, as it insists on being 4.7.1.

Comment: It would be useful to check what's actually going on on the filesystem: do you see folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework/4.7.1?

Comment: Yes, that folder exists. It has a lot of .xml and .dll files.