# How to change visual studio .net install path

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I'm having issues with the .net framework being installed to the wrong drive. I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124805/need-help-retargeting-net-application) a while ago that shows the .net framework is installing to my A: drive instead of C: drive. When I go to install the framework again, the visual studio installer has it locked to the A: drive. I have reinstalled the installer / framework and that does not fix the issue. Is there a way to change the framework location? Thanks for the help.[image: locked to A: drive]

Comment: What is that `A:` drive? USB? My first thought would be to uninstall the problem packages, then log in with a new admin user account and install fresh using that account. I doubt that would be problem free though. What else is on `A:`?

Comment: A: is the other hard drive with photos, games, and other stuff like that.

Comment: I was kind of curious since it says the drive will make Visual Studio perform worse.

Comment: That is because A: is an HDD while C: is an SSD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have installed the **VS IDE** and **shared components, tools and SDKs** on **A** drive and if you want to fix this location into **C** drive, you have to uninstall VS and delete the shared component info from the **Registry Editor**. That is the only way to realize it.

**Suggestions**

**1)** first uninstall VS and then delete this value from **Registry Editor**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\SharedInstallationPath
```

**Then**, rerun `vs_installer` program and you can select the right disk to install it.

**2) Or**, you can run `A:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe` in your side, this program will uninstall all **VS2017** and **VS2019** versions and delete the info from **Registry Editor** at the same time. If you do not care about that, you can use it.

**When** you finish it, you should reinstall VS.

**Update**

To change **VS IDE** installation path, you only have to uninstall VS.

To change the **shared component** folder, you have to modify the key from the **Registry Editor**:

[image]

==================================================

If you only want to change the **shared component** folder, you should note that:

**Note**:

You just modify the value under **registry editor**. The reason we recommend that you reinstall VS and remove the key together is that simply changing the key will not store the files to a new folder. Reinstalling VS will simply put the Shared component into the new file. That is more formal.

**But** simply changing the value does not make much difference. In fact, do not uninstall vs so that you will spend more time downloading the files to the new changed folder next time you change or install.

=================================================

If you also want to change the **VS IDE** path, you have to delete that key and reinstall vs. And change to new path under the **VS_installer UI**.

The **Microsoft**' recommended shared folder path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared`. You can use this if you change it.

Comment: I was able to delete the value from the registry editor, and I'm able to change the install location! However, now I don't know where to install the shared components so the .net framework functions correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For VS IDE, you should reinstall VS to change the install path. But for shared components, you should enter the registry editor to modify that value to change the path.  And if you only wan to change the registry editor, you just modify the value under registry editor.  The reason we recommend that you reinstall VS and remove the key together is that simply changing the key will not store  the files to a new folder. Reinstalling VS will simply put the Shared component into the new file. That is more formal.

Comment: In fact, do not uninstall vs so that you will spend more time downloading the files to the new changed folder next time you change or install.  If you also want to change the VS IDE path, you have to delete that key and reinstall vs. And change to new path under the `vs_installer` UI.

Comment: The Microsoft' recommended shared folder path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared`. You can use this if you change it.

Comment: Making a mistake when editing the registry can break your system. Microsoft should really fix this.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the above answer (I had trouble following it),

#### 1. The default location of shared component (SDK etc.) can be changed by changing the registry value at -

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\SharedInstallationPath`

[image]

here change the registry value to where you want to put shared SDK components.

#### 2. For changing IDE and download cache location -

uninstall (if any) already installed visual studio community(/enterprise etc.) installation.

And then next time when you install it will ask for components to install. In the dialog window make changes to installation location tab.

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have a SharedInstallationPath ?

Comment: is visual studio installer err...installed? Also when checking in registry, the path of hive would be `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup` in which you will find `SharedInstallationPath`.